# Use PDF Core Fonts in wkhtmltopdf/QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

**Questions in a nutshell:**

1. Is it possible to force wkhtmltopdf to use Type1 fonts (PDF core fonts) when generating the pdf?
2. or: Is it possible to force the Qt QPdfEngine to use Type1 fonts (PDF core fonts) when generating the pdf?

**Detailed description of the problem.**

I have developed a webapp to do a pdf-export of a very large database using wkhtmltopdf & tcpdf. The (900+) pages are "printed" using wkhtmltopdf and then "glued together" using tcpdf & fpdi.

Unfortunately wkhtmltopdf seems to always embed the fonts it uses to render the pdf. This is very unwanted behavior as this is redundant and bloats the document. Additionally the document needs to be editable in Acrobat Pro. Apparently Acrobat Pro seems to be overwhelmed by embedded fonts. It tries to replace them upon saving the document, and hangs itself after ~45 minutes on windows machines (on Mac machines it just takes incredibly long to save the document).

So: is there a possibility to tell wkhtmltopdf not to embed fonts and use Type1 Fonts (Helvetica) instead?

I couldn't find any switch to do this so i assumed patching wkhtmltopdf would do the trick by using: printer->setUseEmbeddedFonts(false)

Unfortunately this didn't change anything.

My next idea was patching the Qt-PDF-Printer. Looking into the QPrinter-Class and the QPrintEngine I didn't find any place where the pdf engine uses Type1 fonts instead of embedding the TTF-Fonts (or whatever font is used).

Any ideas and/or pointers?

Comment: I tried to find out this as well. I am 99% sure its not possible. From what I found out neither the font, nor the text, is even in the PDF, its all converted to vectors by the rendering engine. It is unlikly any such option will ever be implemented, as the way the whole program works is to hook into the final vector/raster rendering, so the whole concept of a font or character doesn't even exist at that level. Acrobat tries to be hero software: It can detect which group of vectors are forming a character and even match it to a font.

Comment: Which version of wkhtmltopdf is this?